# Presentation of group $(\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p )\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ for odd prime $p.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, wreath-product

I like to find presentation of the finite non Abelian group $$(\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p )\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_p$$ of order $p^3$, where $p$ is an odd prime. According to me its presentation is $$\langle a,b,c: a^p=b^p=c^p=1, ab=ba, ac=ca, cb=abc\rangle$$
Please suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: @Resident Dementor    thanks for edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Groupprops: Groups of prime-cube order](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_prime-cube_order) shows the same result as yours:

1. There are 5 groups (up to isomorphism) of order $p^3$ for odd prime $p$.
2. Two of them are non-abelian, and one is the semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$, that is not you wanted.
3. The other non-abelian group is the [prime-cube order group: $U(3,p)$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Unitriangular_matrix_group:UT(3,p)) and its [presentation](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Presentations_for_groups_of_prime-cube_order) is
   $$
   \langle a_1,a_2,a_3 \mid a_1^p=e, a_2^p=e, a_3^p=e, [a_1,a_2]=a_3, [a_1,a_3]=e, [a_2,a_3]=e \rangle
   $$
   that is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: It's means my answer is also correct ??

Comment: @neelkanth Sure!

Comment: Thanks.........